# Set cursor in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a simple form with RichTextBox on it. In Load event, I write some text to RichTextBox and now I want to set cursor location to the end of this text so I can add something. I've tried `Focus()` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try :

```
 richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
 richTextBox1.Focus();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either use the CaretPosition property or use the Select(pos, pos) method to achieve the desired result.

Edit:

The Focus method just moves the keyboard focus to your RichTextBox, but it doesn't alter the current position of the cursor inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

For winform application simple add this command `SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");` after `richTextBox1.AppendText("foo");` or `richTextBox1.Paste();` then `richTextBox1.Focus();'