# How can i update cursor position?

Tags: c#, user-interface, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set cursor in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495168/set-cursor-in-richtextbox)

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();          
    text = text.Replace("a", "අ");
    text = text.Replace("අඅ", "ආ");
    richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
}
```

this is my code. in here   after getting result cursor position is come in-front of the letter so how i update cursor position after the letter? please help........

Comment: You can set the SelectionStart value to a number larger than the length of your text. This will automatically place the cursor after the last character. e.g. `this.rechTextBox1.SelectionStart = int.MaxValue;`

Answer (score 1):

```
richTextBox1.Focus();
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

**TextBox.SelectionStart Property:** Gets or sets the starting position of the text selected in the text box. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Edited:**
Here is another option ... if you use `richTextBox1.AppendText` instead of `richTextBox1.Text`, it should automatically put the cursor at the end.

Comment: thanxxxxxxx but still have problem after the searched cursor comes halt of the last character. please help

Comment: @user1462819 after this above two lines write this  richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret

Comment: thanxxxxxxxx i used that method but still have the problem. please help.before i used text box and i used this method TextBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.text.Length; so it's worked properly but when i used richtextBox still it's not work please help me............

Comment: @user1462819 put the focus() function on top and then start selection... See my updated answer

Comment: thanxxxxxxxxxxxx.I used this, richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret(); but still have the problem please help.

Comment: please help.....................................

Comment: have you tried `richTextBox1.AppendText`

Comment: I used this , richTextBox1.Focus();
            richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();  now also cursor doesn't come the right position. it come half of the last letter.

Comment: thanx, i used it, richTextBox1.AppendText(text.ToString()); now append before type text also, still not working please help me.

Comment: where you want the cursor? at the end of text? google it

Comment: yes, i want to cursor at the end of the text

Comment: I searched it google but that codes were not work. thanx for help.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
richTextBox1.Focus();
```

So your event should be:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = richTextBox1.Text;
   text = text.Replace("a", "අ");
   text = text.Replace("අඅ", "ආ");
   text = text.Replace("i", "ඉ");
   richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
   richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
   richTextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the SelectionStart value to a number larger than the length of your text. This will automatically place the cursor after the last character. e.g.     `this.rechTextBox1.SelectionStart = int.MaxValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = richTextBox1.Text;
    text = text.Replace("a", "අ");
    text = text.Replace("අඅ", "ආ");
    text = text.Replace("i", "ඉ");
    this.richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();

    TextPointer caret = this.richTextBox1.CaretPosition;
    caret = caretPos.DocumentEnd;
    this.richTextBox1.CaretPosition = caret;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry if this doesn't help because I could not fully understand your question.