# How cursor put at the end of the text

Tags: c#, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i update cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304542/how-can-i-update-cursor-position)

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string text = richTextBox1.Text;
   text = text.Replace("a", "අ");
   text = text.Replace("අඅ", "ආ");
   text = text.Replace("i", "ඉ");
   richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();
   this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = text.Length;
}
```

I used this but not working after the replace text cursor comes half of the last character and it bind with another character. i used append it also not given correct result. if u know another method for doing this please give answer.